# Automatically adding space in math superscripts

Tags: xetex, superscripts, mathspec

I am using mathspec, but the superscripts in math mode are a bit cramped. This is a well-known problem, so much so that the package defines a command to add space around characters (the double quote). However, it is labour-intensive and it breaks compatibility with Latex. The same goes for adding spaces manually (using, say, `\,`).

Is it possible to increase the space between characters and their superscripts automatically, by, say, redefining some parameter in the preamble?

Here's a MWE showing the problem and the two manual solutions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont                            {Arno Pro}
\setmathsfont   (Latin,Digits,Greek)    {Arno Pro}

\begin{document}

No space: $ V^1 $.

Double quote: $ {"V}^{"1} $.

Manual space: $ V^{\,1} $.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: I'm afraid that, without a real math Arno font, this is the best one can do.

Comment: @egreg Frustrating! Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution which seems to work:

```
\let\sp^
\catcode`\^=\active
\gdef^#1{\sp{\hspace{0.06em} #1}}
```