# Adding space in math superscript in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, overleaf, superscripts, mathspec

I had the same question as asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156118/automatically-adding-space-in-math-superscripts/204316). The solution is to add this piece of code in the preamble

```
\let\sp^
\catcode`\^=\active
\gdef^#1{\sp{\hspace{0.06em} #1}}
```

The solution seems to work. However, I am facing a new problem. I am using overleaf and when I put this into the preamble, the overleaf editor coloring the symbols `^` in red in the above code. Thus I believe the editor does not like how the code is written. This is even more evident in the fact that now for me the auto-compile of overleaf does not work. Auto-compile works when I remove the above lines. Is there a way to rewrite the code such that it doesn't mess up with auto-complication? As I am new to LaTeX, it would be better if someone explains the answer as well.

Comment: Did you contact the Overleaf Help Desk with your question? I hear their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.

Comment: @Mico I just did following your suggestion. Let's see when they reply.

Comment: Generally speaking, the syntax highlighting/colouring of code you are seeing in your editor does not necessarily have a connection to *actual* warning or error messages in your document that you get from TeX. Some editors try to warn you of possible/supposed errors in your document. For example Overleaf parses your document and warns you if `^` is used outside of math mode (which would generally be an error). But when you redefine `^` as shown in the code, you are using `^` outside of math mode. Overleaf's syntax highlighting parser sees this as a possible error, even though it isn't. ...

Comment: ... While the syntax highlighting in some editors are very advanced (Overleaf's highlighting generally seems to perform rather well), they usually can't catch *every possible* legal TeX construct (because you can do crazy stuff in TeX), so if you do unusual things (which you are), you might get some wrong/unexpected code highlighting or a false positive warning message. In the end the only warning and error messages that count are the ones you get from TeX itself, not those from your editor. In Overleaf the errors that are important would be shown with a red marker right of the compile button.

Comment: What I find a bit misleading here though is that Overleaf marks lines containing `^` (that are not detected as being in math mode) with the same error marker it uses to mark actual error locations that are read from the `.log` output. If this further disables auto-compile, then that is annoying, but your options to make Overleaf's parser accept your code are limited. What worked for me in a short test was hiding the code in a different `.tex` file (create a new `.tex` file in your project, say `hidesp.tex`, put the code there, say `\input{hidesp}` in your main document).

Comment: @moewe Thanks! It works with `input` for me.

Comment: @moewe There is a difference in the marking, but only a subtle: the code check also give reddish background to the problematic code on the line. I know it's not much, but it is there.

Comment: @yo' Fair enough. I was mainly looking at the cross icon, which I thought was used only for actual errors from the `.log`.

Comment: @moewe I get it. The thing is, if you decide to use the Code Check, you most likely want the check failures to be treated as errors. If you don't want that, you can simply switch the Code Check off completely in the Menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)*

The advice on how to disable the code check for a part of the document is given in:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Disabling_Code_Check_for_part_of_a_file

You can use `%%begin novalidate` and `%%end novalidate` to mark the part not to be code checked.

```
\documentclass{...}

% Here is the preamble blablabla

%%begin novalidate
\let\sp^
\catcode`\^=\active
\gdef^#1{\sp{\hspace{0.06em} #1}}
%%end novalidate

\begin{document}

Hello, world!

\end{document}
```