# xargs confused about math mode in Overleaf

Tags: macros, overleaf

Why does `newcommandx` warn `array not inside math mode` and cover the Overleaf editor in red while `newcommand` does not?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommand{\myfuncA}[1]{%
  \begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}
}

\newcommandx{\myfuncB}[1]{%
  \begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\myfuncB{hi} \\
\myfuncB{hey}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is ``\\`` allowed inside `\[...\]`? I don't think so. By the way, I get no error.

Comment: I guess this warning is generated (or not) by your editor and not by LaTeX itself. Which editor do you use?

Comment: @Marijn I've edited the OP to clarify.

Comment: @mjc That is just Overleaf's error-checking trying to be helpful.  It doesn't understand that `\newcommandx` is also a `\newcommand`-like thing, so it thinks you are using that in the preamble.  You can safely ignore that.

Comment: Apparently Overleaf doesn't recognize `\newcommandx`. Not a LaTeX problem.

Comment: @mjc You can also go to the Menu -> Code checking, and switch it off

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: @mjc `xparse` does much more than `xargs`, I recommend using it instead.

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf support here. You can disable the code check for parts of your input files using `%%begin novalidate` and `%%end novalidate`, see [https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Disabling_Code_Check_for_part_of_a_file for details](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Disabling_Code_Check_for_part_of_a_file). This is technically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567279/11002 -- I'm not sure how to handle this, and I don't want to provide a completely identical answer here :-/

Comment: @egreg I'm just starting to dip my toes in to `xparse`. For the Overleaf editor, however, it causes the same problem as `newcommandx`.